# Creating Notification Angular2 service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am new in Angular2/Ionic2, try to create Notification kind of services, but have a trouble with understanding why notification message not updated after setTimeout completed. So message get the value but not cleared after setTimeout. Please review the code and give me the way to dig.

Service code:

```ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    public message: string = "";
    public interval: number = 2000;
    public type: boolean = true;

    constructor() {
    }

    public manageMessage(message: string, interval: number, type: boolean) {
        this.message = message;
        this.interval = interval;
        this.type = type;

        setTimeout(
            () => {
                this.message = "";
console.log("cleared");
            },
            this.interval);

        return this.message;
    }
}
```

Sign up component code:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BackandService } from '../../providers/backandService';
import { NotificationService } from '../../providers/notificationService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'signup.html',
  selector: 'page-signup',
})
export class SignupPage {

  email:string = '';
  firstName:string = '';
  lastName:string = '';
  signUpPassword: string = '';
  confirmPassword: string = '';
  message: string = '';

  constructor(private backandService:BackandService, private notificationService: NotificationService) {

  }

  public signUp() {
    if (this.signUpPassword != this.confirmPassword){
      alert('Passwords should match');
      return;
    }
    var $obs = this.backandService.signup(this.email, this.signUpPassword, this.confirmPassword, this.firstName, this.lastName);
    $obs.subscribe(
      data => {
          this.email = this.signUpPassword = this.confirmPassword = this.firstName = this.lastName =  '';
      },
      err => {
          this.backandService.logError(err);
          let messageArray : any;
              try {
                  messageArray = JSON.parse(err._body);
              } catch (e) {
                  messageArray = err._body;
              }

          this.message = this.notificationService.manageMessage(messageArray.error_description, 2000, true);

          this.email = this.signUpPassword = this.confirmPassword = this.firstName = this.lastName =  '';
      },
      () => console.log('Finish Auth'));


  }
```

Signup html template code with form:

```html
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Confirm Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" [value]="confirmPassword" (input)="confirmPassword = $event.target.value"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<div class="message-box" *ngIf="message">
    <p>{{message}}</p>
</div>

<button ion-button (click)="signUp()" color="success">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: You're using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: Edited to settimeout and console.log show "cleared" but new blank string value not binding into template.         setTimeout(
            () => {
                this.message = "";
                console.log("cleared");
            },
            this.interval);

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind to `message` property otherwise the html won't get updated at runtime.you can create a new component which accepets message property as an input and display data in that child component.

```
//child component. message property is minded to this component.
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: ‘message-comp’,
  template: `
    <div>
    {{message}}      
    </div>
  `
})
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input()
  message: string = “”;
}

-----------------------------------------------------------
//parent component this creates  message-comp passing the message
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div class="app">
      <message-comp [message]=“message”></message-comp>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  message: string = “”;

  //you can have functions which will
  //change message,since message property is binded to ‘message-comp’
  //you can access message within that component easily and will get updated when you change it from the
  //parent component    

}
```

Comment: Thank you, to be honest I have tried this approach, but no luck... May be because I am not so experienced in Angular2. Have you any other idea using Service? Why in angular 2 this html message not updated in runtime, when in angular 1 this Service approach works good? BTW if not use service and simply clear value in setTimeout inside Signup() - it is working! But I don\t wont write setTimeout each time I need clear message